# Run R command from command line

Tags: r, command-line

Is there a way to run an R command from the command line? Something like

```
$ R --run '1+1'
2
```

or even like

```
$ Rscript < '1+1'
2
```

Answer (score 18):

The command line option `-e` does exactly that.

```
Rscript.exe -e "1+1"

[1] 2
```

It is clearly explained in the help which you get if you just run `RScript` without parameters:

```
Usage: /path/to/Rscript [--options] [-e expr [-e expr2 ...] | file] [args]

--options accepted are
  --help              Print usage and exit
  --version           Print version and exit
  --verbose           Print information on progress
  --default-packages=list
                      Where 'list' is a comma-separated set
                        of package names, or 'NULL'
or options to R, in addition to --slave --no-restore, such as
  --save              Do save workspace at the end of the session
  --no-environ        Don't read the site and user environment files
  --no-site-file      Don't read the site-wide Rprofile
  --no-init-file      Don't read the user R profile
  --restore           Do restore previously saved objects at startup
  --vanilla           Combine --no-save, --no-restore, --no-site-file
                        --no-init-file and --no-environ

'file' may contain spaces but not shell metacharacters
Expressions (one or more '-e <expr>') may be used *instead* of 'file'
See also  ?Rscript  from within R
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do it with the `R` command:

```
$ R --slave -e '1+1'
[1] 2
```

From `man R`:

```
   --slave
          Make R run as quietly as possible

   -e EXPR
          Execute 'EXPR' and exit
```

Comment: how `R` command compares to `Rscript.exe`?

Comment: Note that [in R 4.0 and later](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2020/000653.html), `--slave` has been renamed to `--no-echo`.

Answer (score 2):

With [`littler` package](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.examples.html) installed and the path of `r` properly configured, you can do something like this:

```
echo 'print(1+1)' | r  
# [1] 2
```

Note, `r` is not a typo. It is a command from `littler`. It also support the `-e` option like `R` and `Rscript`:

```
r -e 'print(1+1)'     
# [1] 2
```

It seems that it only prints when you call `print/cat/...` explicitly in expression.