# How can I execute R one-liners from the terminal without exiting R?

Tags: r, bash, command-line

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45809083/10319707) and its answers show how to open R from your terminal, evaluate the expression that you want to, and then exit R, all in a single line. The cleanest answer is to open your terminal and then run `R --slave -e 'EXPR'` where EXPR is your expression (e.g. `R --slave -e '1+1'`).

My question is this: How can I do all of this without exiting R? That is, I want to, in a single line in my terminal, both enter R and evaluate the expression that I wish to. "Obvious" answers like `R '1+1'` or `R 1+1` don't work, returning the error `ARGUMENT '1+1' __ignored__`, and Bash abuse such as `R; 1+1` refuses to evaluate the second expression until R is closed.

Comment: do you want to evaluate the expression and keep the newly created R process open?

Comment: It's impossible. AFAIK, you can't switch R from non-interactive to interactive mode or vice versa. You have to stick to the one you start with. If you want to use R interactively but run some code before the session starts, you can write your code into an `.Rprofile`, `cd` to its directory, and then start R in an interactive mode. It is the only way I can think of.

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk Yes.

Comment: @ekoam even `echo "1+1" | R --interactive` doesn't work, it just executes the code and stops. I think your suggestion is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a function you can restart R automatically after using the parameters:

```sh
r() {

   # First execute commands when given
   if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
      R --slave -e "$*"
   fi

   # Start R 
   R --slave

}
```

After testing you can add this function to `.bashrc`.
I call the function `r`, but make sure `r` is not already used or reserved by your system.
You can call the function with `r 1+1`, `r 1 + 1` of `r "1*2"`.
Please note the quotes when you use `"1*2"`.
Without quotes the shell will try to expand special characters, and will look for a file "1*2". It would be a lot worse with spaces, `r 1 * 2` will replace `*` with a lot of filenames.

Comment: I like this. What do $# and $* do exactly? Asking for my own edification :)

Comment: `$#` = nr of arguments. `-gt` (greater then) looks for at least 1 argument. `$*` = all aguments. So with the call `r 1+1` you have `$#=1`, `$1=1+1` and `$*=1+1`. With the call `r 1 + 1` you have `$#=3`, `$1=1` and `$*=1 + 1`. With `r` you have `$#=0` and you will skip the part with `-e`.

Comment: Very strange bug: Typing `?` in to my terminal opens R, even after deleting the code in .bashrc

Comment: Two issues: 1. The function `r` is loaded in the memory, deleting the code from `.bashrc` only works after starting a new shell (you can use `unset r` to remove the function from the memory). 2. The `?` is a wildcard. I think, that you have a file called `r`. When you type `echo ?` you will see filenames with 1 character. When the first file is `r`, the shell will try to execute `r`.

Comment: @WalterA `echo ?` returns `R`

Comment: When `echo ?` returns `R`, you have `R` in the current directory. Try it in another directory.

Comment: Tried it elsewhere and it only returned ?

Comment: Just a friendly reminder. There is one problem with this approach. If you run the code and then restart R, results/variables generated in the first session will not be carried over into the second. They will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @ekoam's suggestion easily gets us to what you're looking for, I think:

```sh
# just place this in your .bashrc or .zshrc, etc.
R_expr() {
    # will overwrite your Rprofile each time so use with care.
    echo $1 > .Rprofile 
    exec R
}
```

Now just use your newly created utility `R_expr` whenever you want:

```
jkix $ R_expr "1+1" 
----------------------------------------------------------------
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22) -- "Taking Off Again"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[1] 2
[Previously saved workspace restored]

> print("We did it! We're still in R!")
```

This is really customizable, too:
perhaps you have a script that you want to run and not just an expression:

```sh
R_script() {
    cat $1 > .Rprofile # in this case, the first argument is a script
    exec R 
}
# then...
R_script some_script.R # followed by any options you want
```

The benefit to both of these solutions is that your passed-in code executes at runtime AND any variables defined etc. will be available to the new interactive session. Also, note that you can still pass command-line arguments to `R`:

`R_expr "print('vanilla option used')" --vanilla`.

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

### new answer:

create a script called `oneplusone.R` which contains `1+1`; then run in the terminal `Rscript oneplusone.R`
This returns:

```
tester@LAPTOP MINGW64 ~/Documents
$ Rscript oneplusone.R
[1] 2
```

### old answer:

In my case (I'm running windows), I'd do the following:

1. open CMD
2. change the directory to your R-folder
3. run R.exe
4. run any code

so in CMD:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.3\bin"
R.exe
> 1+1
[1] 2
```

edit: for Linux, have a look at: http://www.cureffi.org/2014/01/15/running-r-batch-mode-linux/

Comment: That's not one line, that's three.

Comment: Would an Rscript solution work for you? Or do you really want to type the expression without predefining it in an R-file?

Comment: Write my code in a separate document first? Come on, that's obviously cheating.